# Angular prevent calling service multiple times

Tags: angular

I have a button that opens  popup where user selects some data and add to my form.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" aria-hidden="true" (click)="addData()"> Add Data</button>

   addData() {
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(PopupComponent,
      { initialState: { createForm: this.createForm }, ignoreBackdropClick: true, animated: true, keyboard: true, class: '' });

      //some code to save below
      //this.bsModalRef.content.onSave 

  }
```

The above opens a pop, user selects some data and press save.

In my popup component I have this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.myService.getData().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
          this.myList = data.map(a => [{ name: a.name }][0]);  
        },
        (error: any) => {
           console.log(error);
        });
   }
```

I then bind myList to my select in my popup component html
   All of the above works fine.

The issue is when the user clicks Add Data it, it open the popup and calls my service again.

Is it possible to avoid the multiple service calls whenever user clicks add again and again.

I tried setting the value of data returned from the api to a variable which gets assigned but on the button click its always empty.

Any input please.

Comment: Ngonit above is part of my popup component, the service call in this gets all the data and binds it to my select dropdown which is a part of my popup component.  The service call being in my popup component OnInit is called everytime the add button is clicked. I want to avoid subsequent calls to the api, once we get the data in myList variable.

Comment: So once the user selects some data, they might come back to select/deselect more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you open the modal, it is initialized from scratch. Since you have the service call on the `ngOnInit` of the modal, it will called each time.
You can possibly change the logic to call `myService.getData` from the main component and then pass this to the modal for each click of *Add Data* button.

Modify your main component to call `myService` and store the result in `myList` during initialisation. Also, modify your `addData()` method to pass this value with the `initialState` to the modal.

```
ngOnInit(){    
    this.myService.getData().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      this.myList = data.map(a => [{ name: a.name }][0]);  
    },
    (error: any) => {
       console.log(error);
    });
}

addData() {
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(PopupComponent,
    { initialState: { createForm: this.createForm, myList: this.myList }, ignoreBackdropClick: true, animated: true, keyboard: true, class: '' });
}
```

Now, `myList` in your modal will already have the required data passed from the main component and the network call can be removed from `ngOnInit` of the modal.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can retrieve the data of `myList` in the form component and then pass it as data in the `Dialog`.